# SELECT * FROM table WHERE row IN ('list')

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm having trouble with the code below, it's giving me a syntax error and I can't find anything in the manual or online about it. What are your thoughts on how I could get this to run?

1st Attempt:

```
<?php
require("../dbpass.php");    $types = array('Buyer','Seller','Buyer / Seller','Investor');
$typeslist = implode ("','", $types);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE contacttype IN ('$typeslist') AND status = 'New' ORDER BY date DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql) or die ("Error: ".mysqli_error($mysqli));
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
```

2nd Attempt (put an "=" after "IN"):

```
<?php
require("../dbpass.php");
$types = array('Buyer','Seller','Buyer / Seller','Investor');
$typeslist = implode ("','", $types);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE contacttype = IN ('$typeslist') AND status = 'New' ORDER BY date DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql) or die ("Error: ".mysqli_error($mysqli));
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
```

This is the rest of the code:

```
$firstname = $row ['firstname'];     

echo'.$firstname.';
}
?>
```

Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IN ('Buyer','Seller','Buyer / Seller','Investor') AND status = 'New' ORDER BY da' at line 1

Comment: Could we have a working link to see the error?

Comment: Can you show us the output of `echo $sql`, or at least the error you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

You have a `;` after your while condition.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)); {
```

Should be

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
```

Comment: Thanks! I wish that was it..see update for error I'm getting.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the =.

```
contacttype IN
```

not

```
contacttype = IN
```

Comment: I tried that as you can see in my "1st Attempt" and it gave me the same syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for query

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE contacttype IN('".$typeslist."') AND status = 'New' ORDER BY date DESC";
```